# Prove that $I_K/ \overline{K^*U}$ is totally disconnected.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, topological-groups, class-field-theory, adeles

For a number field $K$ let $I_K$ be the idele class group and let $$U := \prod _ {\mathfrak q \nmid p} U_\mathfrak q$$ where $\mathfrak q$ is prime in $K$ and $p$ is a prime in $\mathbb Q$. I want to prove that $I_K/ \overline{K^*U}$ is totally disconnected.

It looks like something that should be proved using some result as I don't see how it could be proven from definitions. From the claim 2 of the highest rated answer here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/290075/subgroups-of-a-topological-group-such-that-quotient-space-is-totally-disconnecte it seems that I should prove that $\overline {K^*U}$ contains the connected component of identity. But I cannot figure out how to do that and also the proof of the claim 2 is not short, so I will prefer to see a proof without using that claim.

Comment: If $v$ is an archimedean place, I assume $U_v$ is just $k^{\ast}$.  If so, then modding out by $U$ will eliminate all archimedean components.  So

$$I_K/U \cong K_p^{\ast} \times \bigoplus\limits_{p \neq v < \infty} \mathbb Z$$ where I have used the fact that for $v$ finite, $K_v^{\ast}/U_v \cong \mathbb Z$.  This quotient is already totally disconnected.  Hopefully that is a useful start

Comment: The weak or strong approximation theorems may also help you.  For example, weak approximation tells you that the diagonal embedding of $K^{\ast}$ is dense in any finite product of completions $K_v^{\ast}$, and this may show up somewhere when you take closure.

Comment: @D_S perhaps this works- By strong approximation and your comment above $I_K/\overline{K^*U} $ is a quotient of $\mathbb Z$ which is always discrete thus totally disconnected?